# i would like to build a sort of mobile

Tags: mobile

i would like to build a mobile phone pendent for my little sister

it would only make calls and only to one number

i know of one similar device to what i am looking for: the [Burg 5](http://www.v3.co.uk/v3-uk/blog-post/2083536/burg-watch-pink-fails-tick-boxes)

but i would like it so it can only one number and it would not have the clock face just a big button

the problem is i have no idea were to start

i have heard mutterings of an open source project but it isn't very well explained

Comment: Couple of things: 1. This question, as it stands, is a bit too vague and broad to suit the specific-question and definitive-answer format this site likes. 2. If you hear mutterings of some project, it makes it easier for other members to understand what you are referring to, if you provide links for background. *Automated muttering-transmission* is weak over the Internet.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand you when you don't create sentences (use periods). I have made an attempt to separate out your thoughts. If you agree, edit your question (click the "edit" button under the question) and reform the phrases with periods.

Comment: Did you read the article about the Burg 5?  "The watch phone features a nine-number speed dial memory and a key lock." So it can be made to dial a number without typing that entire number.  Dialing just one number is silly. You want at least two: phone home/parent and 911 (or whatever is the emergency number in your region).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few companies that make cellular modems that you can program.

Sierra Wireless  have modules such as the Q2686, or SL6078 that you can program in C - the dev tools are free and the modules are not too expensive.

Telit also make similar modules that you can program in python.

You would need to design a PCB to connect a battery and SIM card to the module.